# How to make a Bluetooth Slave Device that Automatically connects

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

What I am trying to do is simple in concept: Make the linux computer be a bluetooth slave device that automatically accepts connections (from a phone). The overall goal is to connect automatically and transfer data from a phone app, to python on the linux computer.
Here are the steps that I think are needed:

I first set up the bluetooth adapter using hciconfig:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 noauth
sudo hciconfig hci0 name thisdevice
sudo hciconfig hci0 lm SLAVE
sudo hciconfig hci0 lm ACCEPT
sudo hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1
sudo hciconfig hci0 reset
sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan
```

I then need a bluetooth agent using Bluetoothctl to do the authentication:

```
bluetoothctl
discoverable on
pairable on
agent NoInputNoOutput
```

I then need to connect using my phone. However, in order to connect, I still must type in YES in the terminal within bluetoothctl. (it asks to confirm the right Pin). this is a problem, and defetes the whole purpose of NoInputNoOutput setting.

Then I can run my python program which uses Pybluez and the advertise_service function.
I can then connect to that service from the phone app.

Is this the correct order of events?
How can I make the bluetooth authenticate automatically? (modify the agent code in bluez?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means an expert on this topic, I'd rather say I barely survived trying the exact same thing for 3 days now. I am now giving up and throwing my raspberry pi onto the pile of all the other unfinished projects.

However, I think my tour through this hell might be of value to you. Try typing `agent off` before registering a new agent:

```
bluetoothctl
agent off
agent NoInputNoOutput
discoverable on
pairable on
```

Running `btmon` on a second terminal while typing those commands should show a new NoInputNoOutput agent being registered.

Comment: Hello, I got this working on the server version of Linux. What was messing up the desktop version is the bluetooth manager for the desktop. it always needs user input to connect bluetooth regardless of what bluetoothctl does

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```bash
bt-agent -c NoInputNoOutput -d
```